# Outline the entire bar of geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar

how does one get a black outline around the whole bar, and NOT multiple black outlines like in the example plot below:

```
`diamonds %>% 
select(carat, cut) %>% 
distinct() %>% 
ggplot() +
geom_bar(aes(x=factor(cut), y=factor(carat), fill=factor(carat)), 
     stat = "identity", colour="black") +
theme(legend.position = "none")`
```

I want the "colour=black" to surround each bar.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, you do have a black border around each bar. However, for every `cut`, you have plenty of bars, one for each value of `carat`. If what you want is a black border around each stack of bars, then I would recommend to plot first with a border, and second without border:

```
diamonds %>% 
  select(carat, cut) %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_bar(aes(x=factor(cut), y=factor(carat)), 
           stat = "identity", color = "black", size = 1) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=factor(cut), y=factor(carat), fill=factor(carat)), 
           stat = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Gives:
[image: Output]